# Android Application closes after submit answer button is pressed

Tags: java, android

So basically, I have a license quiz android application. After I check all of the questions or only a few of them and press the submit button instead of throwing me the message of how many I did the program just closes with no warning or whatever. After a brief seconds it tells me that the application itself keeps closing.

```
Import :

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.Toast;





Main activity :

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    // Question 1
    CheckBox question1_choice1;
    CheckBox question1_choice2;
    CheckBox question1_choice3;
    CheckBox question1_choice4;
    CheckBox question1_choice5;
    CheckBox question1_choice6;

    // Question 2
    CheckBox question2_choice1;
    CheckBox question2_choice2;
    CheckBox question2_choice3;
    CheckBox question2_choice4;

    // Question 3
    CheckBox question3_choice1;
    CheckBox question3_choice2;
    CheckBox question3_choice3;

    // Question 4
    CheckBox question4_choice1;
    CheckBox question4_choice2;
    CheckBox question4_choice3;
    CheckBox question4_choice4;

    // Question 5
    CheckBox question5_choice1;
    CheckBox question5_choice2;
    CheckBox question5_choice3;
    CheckBox question5_choice4;

    // Question 6
    CheckBox question6_choice1;
    CheckBox question6_choice2;
    CheckBox question6_choice3;

    // Question 7
    CheckBox question7_choice1;
    CheckBox question7_choice2;
    CheckBox question7_choice3;
    CheckBox question7_choice4;
    // Question 8
    CheckBox question8_choice1;
    CheckBox question8_choice2;
    CheckBox question8_choice3;
    CheckBox question8_choice4;
    // Question 9
    CheckBox question9_choice1;
    CheckBox question9_choice2;
    CheckBox question9_choice3;
    CheckBox question9_choice4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Hide the keyboard
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    public void submitAnswers(View view) {
        CharSequence resultsDisplay;
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, " " + this.findViewById(R.id.question3_choice3));
        int answer1_score;
        int answer2_score;
        int answer3_score;
        int answer4_score;
        int answer5_score;
        int answer6_score;
        int answer7_score;
        int answer8_score;
        int answer9_score;
        int final_score;

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Question 1 - Corect 1 - 4 - 5;
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Boolean answer1_choice1;
        Boolean answer1_choice2;
        Boolean answer1_choice3;
        Boolean answer1_choice4;
        Boolean answer1_choice5;
        Boolean answer1_choice6;
        question1_choice1 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question1_choice1);
        question1_choice2 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question1_choice2);
        question1_choice3 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question1_choice3);
        question1_choice4 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question1_choice4);
        question1_choice5 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question1_choice5);
        question1_choice6 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question1_choice6);
        answer1_choice1 = question1_choice1.isChecked();
        answer1_choice2 = question1_choice2.isChecked();
        answer1_choice3 = question1_choice3.isChecked();
        answer1_choice4 = question1_choice4.isChecked();
        answer1_choice5 = question1_choice5.isChecked();
        answer1_choice6 = question1_choice6.isChecked();
        if (answer1_choice1 && !answer1_choice2 && !answer1_choice3 && answer1_choice4 && answer1_choice5 && !answer1_choice6) {
            answer1_score = 1;
        } else {
            answer1_score = 0;
        }
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Question 2 - Corect - 3
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Boolean answer2_choice1;
        Boolean answer2_choice2;
        Boolean answer2_choice3;
        Boolean answer2_choice4;
        question1_choice1 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question2_choice1);
        question1_choice2 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question2_choice2);
        question1_choice3 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question2_choice3);
        question1_choice4 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question2_choice4);
        answer2_choice1 = question2_choice1.isChecked();
        answer2_choice2 = question2_choice2.isChecked();
        answer2_choice3 = question2_choice3.isChecked();
        answer2_choice4 = question2_choice4.isChecked();
        if (!answer2_choice1 && !answer2_choice2 && answer2_choice3 && !answer2_choice4) {
            answer2_score = 1;
        } else {
            answer2_score = 0;
        }
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Question 3  - Corect 2
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Boolean answer3_choice1;
        Boolean answer3_choice2;
        Boolean answer3_choice3;
        question3_choice1 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question3_choice1);
        question2_choice2 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question3_choice2);
        question3_choice3 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question3_choice3);
        answer3_choice1 = question3_choice1.isChecked();
        answer3_choice2 = question3_choice2.isChecked();
        answer3_choice3 = question3_choice3.isChecked();

        if (!answer3_choice1 && answer3_choice2 && !answer3_choice3) {
            answer3_score = 1;
        } else {
            answer3_score = 0;
        }
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Question 4 - Corect - 4
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Boolean answer4_choice1;
        Boolean answer4_choice2;
        Boolean answer4_choice3;
        Boolean answer4_choice4;
        question4_choice1 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question4_choice1);
        question4_choice2 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question4_choice2);
        question4_choice3 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question4_choice3);
        question4_choice4 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question4_choice4);
        answer4_choice1 = question4_choice1.isChecked();
        answer4_choice2 = question4_choice2.isChecked();
        answer4_choice3 = question4_choice3.isChecked();
        answer4_choice4 = question4_choice4.isChecked();

        if (!answer4_choice1 && !answer4_choice2 && !answer4_choice3 && answer4_choice4) {
            answer4_score = 1;
        } else {
            answer4_score = 0;
        }
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Question 5  - Corect - 4
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Boolean answer5_choice1;
        Boolean answer5_choice2;
        Boolean answer5_choice3;
        Boolean answer5_choice4;
        question5_choice1 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question5_choice1);
        question5_choice2 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question5_choice2);
        question5_choice3 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question5_choice3);
        question5_choice4 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question5_choice4);
        answer5_choice1 = question5_choice1.isChecked();
        answer5_choice2 = question5_choice2.isChecked();
        answer5_choice3 = question5_choice3.isChecked();
        answer5_choice4 = question5_choice4.isChecked();

        if (!answer5_choice1 && !answer5_choice2 && !answer5_choice3 && answer5_choice4) {
            answer5_score = 1;
        } else {
            answer5_score = 0;
        }
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Question 6 - Corect 3
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Boolean answer6_choice1;
        Boolean answer6_choice2;
        Boolean answer6_choice3;
        question6_choice1 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question6_choice1);
        question6_choice2 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question6_choice2);
        question6_choice3 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question6_choice3);
        answer6_choice1 = question6_choice1.isChecked();
        answer6_choice2 = question6_choice2.isChecked();
        answer6_choice3 = question6_choice3.isChecked();

        if (!answer6_choice1 && answer6_choice2 && answer6_choice3) {
            answer6_score = 1;
        } else {
            answer6_score = 0;
        }
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Question 7  - Corect 2 - 4
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Boolean answer7_choice1;
        Boolean answer7_choice2;
        Boolean answer7_choice3;
        Boolean answer7_choice4;
        question7_choice1 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question7_choice1);
        question7_choice2 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question7_choice2);
        question7_choice3 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question7_choice3);
        question7_choice4 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question7_choice4);
        answer7_choice1 = question7_choice1.isChecked();
        answer7_choice2 = question7_choice2.isChecked();
        answer7_choice3 = question7_choice3.isChecked();
        answer7_choice4 = question7_choice4.isChecked();
        if (!answer7_choice1 && answer7_choice2 && !answer7_choice3 && answer7_choice4) {
            answer7_score = 1;
        } else {
            answer7_score = 0;
        }
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Question 8 - Correct Answer is "Wrist"
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Boolean answer8_choice1;
        Boolean answer8_choice2;
        Boolean answer8_choice3;
        Boolean answer8_choice4;
        question8_choice1 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question8_choice1);
        question8_choice2 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question8_choice2);
        question8_choice3 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question8_choice3);
        question8_choice4 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question8_choice4);
        answer8_choice1 = question8_choice1.isChecked();
        answer8_choice2 = question8_choice2.isChecked();
        answer8_choice3 = question8_choice3.isChecked();
        answer8_choice4 = question8_choice4.isChecked();
        if (!answer8_choice1 && !answer8_choice2 && answer8_choice3 && !answer8_choice4) {
            answer8_score = 1;
        } else {
            answer8_score = 0;
        }
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Question 9  - Correct Answers is #2 "Stalagmites"
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Boolean answer9_choice1;
        Boolean answer9_choice2;
        Boolean answer9_choice3;
        Boolean answer9_choice4;
        question9_choice1 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question9_choice1);
        question9_choice2 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question9_choice2);
        question9_choice3 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question9_choice3);
        question9_choice4 = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.question9_choice4);
        answer9_choice1 = question9_choice1.isChecked();
        answer9_choice2 = question9_choice2.isChecked();
        answer9_choice3 = question9_choice3.isChecked();
        answer9_choice4 = question9_choice4.isChecked();
        if (!answer9_choice1 && !answer9_choice2 && !answer9_choice3 && answer9_choice4) {
            answer9_score = 1;
        } else {
            answer9_score = 0;
        }
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Final Score
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        final_score = answer1_score + answer2_score + answer3_score + answer4_score + answer5_score +
                answer6_score + answer7_score + answer8_score + answer9_score;

        if (final_score == 9) {
            resultsDisplay = "Perfect! Ai rezolvat 9 din 9";
        } else {
            resultsDisplay = "Ai rezolvat " + final_score + " din 9";
        }

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, resultsDisplay, duration);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }

Main activity.xml :

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="rocks.athrow.android_quiz_app.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/quiz_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="@string/question1"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question1_choice1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question1_choice1" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question1_choice2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question1_choice2" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question1_choice3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question1_choice3" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question1_choice4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question1_choice4" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question1_choice5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question1_choice5" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question1_choice6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question1_choice6" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="@string/question2"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question2_choice1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question2_choice1" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question2_choice2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question2_choice2" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question2_choice3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question2_choice3" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question2_choice4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question2_choice4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="@string/question3"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question3_choice1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question3_choice1" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question3_choice2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question3_choice2" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question3_choice3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question3_choice3" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="@string/question4"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question4_choice1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question4_choice1" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question4_choice2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question4_choice2" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question4_choice3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question4_choice3" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question4_choice4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question4_choice4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="@string/question5"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question5_choice1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question5_choice1" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question5_choice2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question5_choice2" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question5_choice3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question5_choice3" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question5_choice4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question5_choice4" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="@string/question6"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question6_choice1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question6_choice1" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question6_choice2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question6_choice2" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/question6_choice3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/question6_choice3" />
```

Log error :

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
                  at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
                  at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
                  at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
                  at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.CheckBox.isChecked()' on a null object reference
                  at rocks.athrow.android_quiz_app.MainActivity.submitAnswers(MainActivity.java:128)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
                  at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
                  at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: You should have some thing coming up in the log due to that.?

Comment: Forgot about the log, here is it

Comment: Can you post it in your question

Comment: @Psypher refresh the page, I added it as you placed your comment.

Comment: What is in line 128 in MainActivity?

Comment: Fixed, I had some duplicated variables in my code. Ty for help.